# hide the bottom navigation bar if cart is empty flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, flutter-widget

I am adding the products to cart and displaying the total amount in the bottom navigation bar ,if the cart is empty i want to show another screen in the same page i.e

[image]

and if cart is not empty i want to show

[image]

```
    body: _getitemCon.get_cart_item == null
          ?
      Center(
              child:_canShowButton?emptycart(): SizedBox(),
            )
          : new ListView(),
bottomNavigationBar: Container()
```

this is how i tried to show the screens in same page

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the `bottomNavigationBar` with `Visibility` widget, like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Visibility(visible: condition, child: Container())
```

Then, the condition to show the `bottomNavigationBar` in your case seems to be `_getitemCon.get_cart_item != null`. Just make sure to call `setState` when you update the condition.